# In .Net Core 2.2 please how can I use a custom UserStore with the default .Net UserManager or must I build a UserManager from scratch?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, identity, usermanager

I have built an identity system by scaffolding my entities into database (Code-First), built an EmployeeStore that inherits from IUserStore, however, whenever my OnPost method tries to use the NormalizedUserName method in EmployeeStore, I always get a traceback error to the UserManager (Please check error below)

**Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NullReferenceException
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Nextekk.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
   at Nextekk.Models.EmployeeStore.SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(Employee employee, String normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/Xxxxxx/Nxxxxxx/Models/EmployeeStore.cs:line 113
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.d__82.MoveNext()**

I have even tried to inject the UserManager into the constructor of EmployeeStore and call it to use the UserManager directly which I really do not want as an option but all for nothing.

My NormalizedUserName method looks like this:

```
public Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(Employee employee, string normalizedName,      CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        if (employee == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));
        }
        if (normalizedName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(normalizedName));
        }

        // base.SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(Employee employee, string normalizedName,     CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        employee.NormalizedUserName = normalizedName;
        // db.SaveChanges();
        // return Task.CompletedTask;
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

and my startup Identity Service looks like this below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {


        services.AddDbContext<Models.NextekkDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NDB")));
        // Add identity
        services.AddIdentity<Employee, Role>()
        .AddUserStore<EmployeeStore>()
        .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<NextekkDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<EmployeeClaimsPrincipalFactory>(); 


        services.AddScoped<EmployeeClaimsPrincipalFactory>();




        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);



    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseAuthentication();
```

Please my question is how to make my CustomUserStore (EmployeeStore) work with Microsoft Identity’s default UserManager. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two important information is missing I guess, Where does the Employee object comes from, which line is raising the exception, Does just setting the `employee.NormalizedUserName` throws this exception?

Comment: The Employee is a Class in my Model directory and has been referenced with ‘using’. employee is it’s instance.

Also employee.NormalizedUserName (from NormalizedUserName method in EmployeeStore) throws the exception which then traces back to UserManager

Comment: So what code is at `Models/EmployeeStore.cs:line 113`

Comment: Jeremy This is the code at line 113 : employee.NormalizedUserName = normalizedName;  // Mat J, YES, setting this value raises the exception error on this line